# is GA using arrays as associative?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.mydomain.com']);
```

I'm confused here, is GA pushing two new elements onto _gaq array or is this an associative key-value pair being pushed onto _gaq?

I'm just trying to understand JS better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither :)

It's pushing a new array with two elements into `_gaq`

It's probably acting like a key-value pair internally to the GA code, but JS doesn't see it like that.